# Bootstrap 4 - Is there a way where you can centre text for desktops and have no centre for mobile?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This is what code I have for the header I want the two pictures to be either end preferably at the corners but that is another problem. And have the text directly on the centre on a desktop where on mobile all the images and text are stacked is that possible?

To view the code in full
https://jsfiddle.net/s9n4hrvs/

```
 <img class="rounded float-left" src="wpimages/wp7dd375bf.png" alt="" >

 <div class="col-6   "><h1>Ring <p></p> 01427 752095</h1></div>

 <img class="rounded float-right" src="wpimages/Capture.PNG" alt="" >
```

Comment: Can you post all of the relevant code?

Comment: @ZimSystem I have made fiddle thing where you can view all the code. https://jsfiddle.net/s9n4hrvs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "centre text for desktops and have no centre for mobile?"

Yes, using the [responsive text alignment utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/#text-alignment)...

For example, here's align center on `md and up`, align left on `xs` and `sm`...

```
<div class="col-6 bg-light text-md-center text-left">
     <h1>Ring <p></p> 01427 752095</h1>
</div>
```